# How to get the current line number from an executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is there a function or keyword that will allow me to get the current line number in a stored procedure?

I know there's an undocumented `LineNo` function that allows you to set the line number, and affect the output of system error messages
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054511/what-exactly-does-the-t-sql-lineno-reserved-word-do

I know there's a function `ERROR_LINE()` that's available inside of a `BEGIN CATCH ... END CATCH`.

`ERROR_LINE()` does what I need, but I want to use it from outside a CATCH block. Anywhere in the file.

```
 DECLARE @InsertSource VARCHAR(1000) = object_name(@@procid)
 EXEC PROC_Accounting_Transaction_Insert ... other parameters..., @InsertSource
```

Currently I'm just hard-coding the call # as it appears in the stored procedure body, but it's getting old quickly.

```
DECLARE @InsertSource VARCHAR(1000) 

SET @InsertSource = object_name(@@procid) + '#1'
EXEC ...

SET @InsertSource = object_name(@@procid) + '#2'
EXEC ...
```

Comment: For your intended purpose, I would think that you are better off with your current implementation of specifying `#1`, etc as those markers will still be relevant as you add/remove/change code in this Stored Proc (assuming you never re-assign one of those call numbers).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question actually came up 2.5 years ago on StackOverflow, and I posted an Answer there:

[SQL print line number in comment of dynamically created stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850270/sql-print-line-number-in-comment-of-dynamically-created-stored-procedure/19916706#19916706)

The relevant portion of that Answer is copied below:

---

You can use `TRY` / `CATCH` with a forced error as the `CATCH` block can return the line number that the error occurred on via the `ERROR_LINE()` function. The full construct, formatted for readability, is:

```sql
DECLARE @Line INT = -1; -- default to an invalid line #

-- some code

BEGIN TRY
    ;THROW 50000, 'Line#', 1; -- all 3 values are arbitrary, but required
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @LineNumber = ERROR_LINE();
END CATCH

-- some code
```

Now, to get the `@LineNumber` variable to populate with the line number that it is being set on, you can reduce that construct to a single line as follows:

```sql
BEGIN TRY;THROW 50000,'',1;END TRY BEGIN CATCH;SET @Line=ERROR_LINE();END CATCH
```

Please note that the `THROW` command started in SQL Server 2012. If you are using SQL Server 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2, then you need to use `RAISERROR()` function instead of `THROW`.

Answer (score 7):

[Adam Machanic](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/) sent me this in email

```
DECLARE @lineno INT
BEGIN TRY SET @lineno = 1/0 END TRY BEGIN CATCH SET @lineno = ERROR_LINE() END CATCH
```

It does qualify as a one line in my book.

Per @ScottGartner, a true one-liner.

```
BEGIN TRY print 1/0; END TRY BEGIN CATCH print 'Line Number: ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() as nvarchar(20)); END CATCH;
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, I just remembered (and found) that I had posted this  a couple of years ago on StackOverflow: [SQL print line number in comment of dynamically created stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850270/sql-print-line-number-in-comment-of-dynamically-created-stored-procedure/19916706#19916706) ;-)

Comment: @srutzky Cross post your answer and I will mark correct.

Comment: Here's an simpler version if all you want to do is print it out: BEGIN TRY print 1/0; END TRY BEGIN CATCH print 'Line Number: ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() as nvarchar(20)); END CATCH;

Comment: @ScottGartner that's a great alternative.